# How to dynamically add options to a select element via data from a database?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I have a form that requires fetching data from a Supabase database and using that to fill the options of the select input.

My current code looks like this:

```js
"use client";

export default function Home() {
  const handleSubmit = (formData: FormData) => {
    const data = {
      grade: formData.get("grade"),
      section: formData.get("section")
    };

    alert(
      `Grade: ${data.grade} Section: ${data.section}`
    );
  };

  return (
    <form action={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="grade" />
      <select name="section">
        {/* generate here */}
        <option value=""></option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

I have a basic data fetching system for this, but I am not sure if it will work. Server and Client components are kind of confusing right now.

I am using Next.js 13 with server components enabled.